# How recover account and emails from Windows Live Mail?

Tags: windows-7, windows, email, windows-live-mail, windows-live

First I change the path of the C:\Users\Valter\Documents to D:\Document\Windows (in Windows 7 Professional) and when I enter in the my Windows Live Mail, my account and emails gone.
How do I recover that ?

Any idea ? I really need help with this guys.
Thank you for your attention with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail is stored in you user folder (eg: 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Mail').  You moved them, so you'll need to update Live Mail with the new path.

- In Windows Live Mail, press ALT to bring up the menu and select Tools, then Options.
- Click the Advanced tab, then the Maintenance button.
- Click the Store Folder button, Change it to the new path.

[image]

Comment: thanks dude.
I restore the path to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Mail, it seems to work, but I had two accounts on it, but imports just one, do you know why this happens ?